# How to filter category with custom attribute Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, category, collection, category-attribute

I added a custom category attribute type yes/no like this:
[image]

In eav_attribute table:
[image]

the problem is when i filter follow this attribute it return empty array:

```
$model = $this->categoryFactory->create();
$categories = $model->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('show_category', 1)
->addIsActiveFilter();
```

Any help? Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this :- 

namespace NameSpace\Module\Block;

    class FeaturedCategories extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{


     protected $categoryCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getFeaturedCategories()
    {
        $collection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('show_category', '1');

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answers but it still not working for me.

Comment: what error you are facing in code ?